# How can I prove that $\mu(\{0\}) \neq 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Suppose $\mu$ is a finite measure on the Borel subsets of $\mathbb R$ such that

$f(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x+t)\mu(dt)$ a.e.

where $f$ is real-valued, bounded, and integrable. Compute $\mu(\{0\})$.

Of course I know that the answer is 1, by letting $f(x)=\mathbb 1_{\{0\}}$, assuming that the equality $f(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x+t)\mu(dt)$ also holds at $x=0$.

However, the equality holds 'almost' everywhere, not everywhere, so we have to prove that the equality holds at $x=0$. I think that it suffices to prove that $\mu(\{0\})\neq 0$ since the equality holds a.e., so the set of points where the equality don't hold has zero measure. Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can prove that $\mu$ is zero on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0\}$ by considering functions $1_B$ for some Borel sets $B$? Then $\mu(\{ 0\}) \neq 0$ follows because it clearly cannot be the zero measure.

Comment: Is the equality true $\mu$ almost everywhere or $\lambda$ almost everywhere, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo $\mu$-almost everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. $\mu$ is a probability measure. Did you try to compute its characteristic function/Fourier transform?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo No. I've never learned probability theory. This problem is from Bass, <Real Analysis for Graduate Students>, chapter 15 <$L^p$ Spaces>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that we don't have $f(0) = \int f(t) \, \mu(dt)$ but since the equality is valid *almost everywhere* we have
$$
1 = \chi_{\{x\}}(x) 
= \int \chi_{\{x\}}(x+t) \, \mu(dt)
= \int \chi_{\{0\}}(t) \, \mu(dt)
= \mu(\{0\})
$$
for almost every $x \in \mathbb R$. Here we have used that $\chi_{\{x\}}(x+t) = \chi_{\{0\}}(t)$.

As this equality is valid for almost every $x \in \mathbb R$ it must be valid for some $x$. Thus, $\mu(\{0\}) = 1$.

---

Also see [Suppose $\mu$ is a finite measure on the Borel sets of $R$ such that $f(x) = \int_R f(x + t) \mu(dt)$ a.e., show $\mu(\{0\}) = 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402437/suppose-mu-is-a-finite-measure-on-the-borel-sets-of-r-such-that-fx-in?rq=1)